# после нажатия alt , ctrl не отлавливает WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

```
 public void ZoomViewBody(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt))
            {
                //код...
            }
        }
public void ZoomViewDistance(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
            {
                //код...
            }
        }
```

После нажатия Аlt, Ctrl не отлавливает. Нужно ПРОСТО нажать Alt снова,чтобы CTRL снова начал отлавливать.
В режиме Дебаг заходит без проблем в код ViewDistance и выполняет код.

Помогите решить вопрос :D
Пожалуйста)

Comment: Как можно исправить ? :D

Comment: Для уточнений, редактируйте вопрос, кнопка "править"

Comment: Все ли Вы рассказали о проблеме? К чему "привинчены"  ZoomViewBody и ZoomViewDistance? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Потому что Alt переводит фокус на меню (или какой-то другой элемент)

Comment: Это стандартное поведение операционки.

Comment: Александр Муксимов, да, обо всем что нужно) Весь остальной код закомментирован и все равно присутствует баг.

Comment: Как можно исправить данный баг? Без костылей желательно :D Пока идея только - эмулировать нажатие Alt

Answer (score 1):

Ответ собранный из разных источников.
Искал по запросам: "wpf отключить поведение alt", "wpf после нажатия alt приложение замирает" и т.д.

Alt - клавиша модификатор.
В MVVM используется так

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Alt"
            Key="D"
            Command="{Binding ...}" />
```

Такое поведение определяется операционной системой.
Если нажать и отпустить Alt, а потом нажать стрелку вниз, откроется меню.
Такое же поведение может быть у клавиши F10.
Нажатие Alt+кнопки на цифровой клавиатуре(Numpad) зарезервировано для ввода символов
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Коды сообщений
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-syskeydown

Коды клавиш
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

**Как решить проблему**:

```
<Window x:Class=...
    Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded">
        
using System.Windows.Interop;

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle)?.AddHook(WndProc);
}

private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
private const int VK_MENU = 0x12;

private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN && wParam.ToInt32() == VK_MENU)
        handled = true;

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Здесь решение для WindowsForms
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090994/disable-normal-behavior-of-alt-key

Здесь ответ по поводу мыши
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485091/wpf-intercept-global-mouse-movements-like-using-imessagefilter-in-windows-form

Comment: благодарю)) 
Те кто будут искать, да найдут